# Testing syslog-ng on CentOS 8

Tags: logging, syslog, centos-8

I am relatively new to Linux and networking but was tasked with the following at work:
I built up a CentOS VM machine ( using VirtualBox) on which I had to install Splunk Heavy Forwarder and syslog-ng.
The idea is that syslog-ng will listen on a port for incoming logs and write them to a file. After that I will ingest these logs in Splunk doing file monitoring on that specific file.

I came to two problems.

1. I am not sure that I configured syslog-ng correctly since I find it difficult to simulate traffic. I was told to try with netcat. What I did was as follows:

- I create /var/log/syslog-ng/testlog.txt file which has the following permissions -rw-r--r--
- My source driver in syslog-ng.conf -

  source s_test { network
  (
  ip("127.0.0.1")
  transport("tcp")
  port(2514)
  );
  };
- My destination driver is -

destination d_tests
{
file
(
"/var/log/syslog-ng/testlog.txt"
);
};

- My log statement is -

  log { source(s_test); destination(d_test); destination(d_tests); };
- I tried to simulate traffic using nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2514 but it yields error that q is an invalid option for nc.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind.  I successfully simulated the traffic with echo "message" | nc 127.0.0.1 2514. Now I have another ask. CAn someone help me conf the syslog-ng conf file in such a manner that syslog-ng would listen on 3 different port for input from three different sources. I'd like to write each sources logs to a different file on the centos VM so that I can do 3 file monitors in Splunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create three different sources:

source s_test { network ( ip("127.0.0.1") transport("tcp") port(2514) ); };

source s_test2 { network ( ip("127.0.0.1") transport("tcp") port(2515) ); };

source s_test3 { network ( ip("127.0.0.1") transport("tcp") port(2516) ); };

Also create three destinations and log paths.

You can simulate traffic using the **loggen** command of syslog-ng.

Comment: Yeah sound logical, isnt it lol.

Comment: I'll also try the loggen command

Comment: Something went incredibly wrong. I did as you said creating 3 sources, destinations and log paths and now when I try to restart it's throwing me error:

Comment: capabilities, capability management disabled; error='Operation not permitted'
[2020-08-04T07:33:50.887591] Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/usr/lib64/syslog-ng', module='http'
[2020-08-04T07:33:50.889064] Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/usr/lib64/syslog-ng', module='http'
[2020-08-04T07:33:50.889359] Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/usr/lib64/syslog-ng', module='http'
[2020-08-04T07:33:50.892116] Error creating persistent state file; filename='/var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.persist-', error='Permission denied (13)'

Comment: It was permission issue. I logged in as a root and fiedit. Now it throws another error: Error initializing message pipeline; plugin_name='syslog', location='/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:35:9'

Comment: I got it, I was using port that was already in use by another source driver.